# Is there a way to filter a pandas dataframe row by arrays in the column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe for which the output is this:

```
     fruit                     season
0   apples      [plant, plant, plant]
1  oranges    [harvest, plant, plant]
2  bananas  [harvest, plant, harvest]
```

I want to search for a pattern in the season column ...

```
pattern = [harvest, plant, plant]
```

... so it shows me a filtered dataframe with the give pattern like this:

```
1  oranges    [harvest, plant, plant]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not misinterpreting you want the rows with that exact value to be shown: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

```
pattern = ['harvest', 'plant', 'plant']     
df.loc[df['season'] == pattern]
```

Comment: Not working here

Comment: This also does not work.